# e(fx)clipse how to disable Warning "JavaFX controller method must have 0 or exactly 1 argument"

Tags: javafx, fxml, efxclipse

e(fx)clipse shows the warning on every function with ChangeListener signature which is annotated with @FXML

```
@FXML
private void fldMyTextFieldChanged( ObservableValue< ? extends String > observable, String oldValue, String newValue ) {
    doSomethingIcredible();
}
```

The corresponding FXML looks like

```
<TextField fx:id="fldMyTextField"
    text="Results in annoying warnings"
    onTextChange="#fldMyTextFieldChanged" />
```

According to the FXML-documentation change-listeners can be attached this way - and it does work fine with the exception that e(fx)clipse issues that annoying warning (if you have numerous TextFields that clutters the Warnings).

I tried to locate a corresponding entry in the Compiler-Settings (Warnings and Errors) but could not find an entry to reconfigure the behaviour.

I also tried several approaches with @SuppressWarnings-annotations using parts of the warning. But that didn't work either and resulted in Warnings at the annotation itself reading something like

```
Unsuported @UnsupportedWarnings("JafaFX").
```

Any suggestions? - Thanks

PS: I use the latest e(fx)clipse and currently OpenJDK 19 in combination mit JPMS (Java Modules) - if somebody is wondering

Comment: There are a number of FXML features that IDEs are not aware of: property change listeners are unsupported in all IDEs I've tried. (Expression bindings in FXML also have poor support.) I haven't found a fix for this.

Comment: Thanks - I was aware that e(fx)clipse was the source of the quirk. In addition the FXML-documentation is slightly outdated (Oracle offers only FXML-documentation for JavaFX 8.0)

Comment: Your link shows a version that was last updated in May 2017 - which is 4 years "fresher" than the version I posted. It

Comment: FYI Your version has an additional small chapter about Java-modules (JPMS)